# Java Stream - How to produce Null as a result using reduce() when the Stream is Empty with Java 8

Tags: java, null, java-stream

I have the following snippet of code, where `items` is a list of type `List<BigDecimal>`:

```
BigDecimal output = items.stream()
    .filter(Objects::notnull)
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

And I have the following test cases:

```
a. Input -> List<BigDecimal> items = Arrays.asList(null, 4);
   Expected output: 4

b. Input -> List<BigDecimal> items = Arrays.asList(null, 4, 3);
   Expected output: 7

c. Input -> List<BigDecimal> items = Arrays.asList(null, null);
   Expected output: null
```

My code is failing for test-case `C`, the output it produces is a `BigDecimal` having the value of `0` instead of `null`.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have provided the *identity* (the first argument of the `reduce()`, which serves as the starting point for folding a stream) as `BigDecimal.ZERO`, it would be returned in case when the stream is empty.

We can use another flavor of [`reduce(accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) which expect only one argument - *accumulator* function, and returns an `Optional`. This version treats the first stream element that reaches it as an *identity*, and if the stream appears to be empty, the method would return an empty optional.

To return `null` as default value if the *stream is empty*, we can apply [`orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) method on the *optional result* returned by `reduce()`.

```
BigDecimal output = items.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // produces a stream of non-null elements
    .reduce(BigDecimal::add)  // Optional<BigDecimal>
    .orElse(null);            // BigDecimal
```

Comment: @nainadas By the way, you said that your code produces `0` for the list `[null,null]` which can't be the case. That mean your stream differ from the one you've posted. Can you **please share** the **actual code** you were running (so that the code would match your description) ? That would make your question more helpful for others.

Comment: Hi Alex,I  was trying below: output=items.stream().filter(Objects::NonNull).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal::add)..This is giving me 0  as output.. I some how missed that orElse part as I am new to java .Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: @nainadas That's better. I've improved both your question and my answer.